# Lualatex and fontspec - Compile to DOCX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, pandoc

I've written a thing in LaTeX that I need to submit as a docx or doc file. I have a font that I specified with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ FONT }
```

If I `pandoc assignment.tex -o assignment.docx` (or to HTML, ODT, from PDF, etc) the font is replaced with Times New Roman and the double spacing is removed (`\usepackage{setspace}` and `\doublespacing`). In additon, some newlines have a grey background color, which is really weird. Using lualatex to compile to a pdf works perfectly, and then nothing else  works at all. I've seen multiple questions about compiling to a docx, but none of the proposed solutions ended up working. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: You're lucky if it just gives you those general formatting problems, which are easily solvable. If you need to make this conversion often, maybe using a custom Word template could solve the problem of the font and interline spacing.

Comment: @Fran ah okay, thanks.